# Is there an API equivilent of the "Upload and Deploy" button in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there an API equivilent of the "Upload and Deploy" button in elastic beanstalk?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a group of 3 api's

I'll use aws CLI syntax:

```
s3api put-object --bucket value --key value --body file.zip
elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name myapp --version-label someversion --source-bundle S3Bucket=value,S3Key=value
elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name --version-label someversion
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach took but with powershell :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java code used to deploy new project to existing environment.

```
        //To deploy new war file to the enviroinment
            CreateStorageLocationResult location = service.beansTalk().createStorageLocation();
            String bucket = location.getS3Bucket();
            File file = new File("FirstServlet.war");
            PutObjectRequest object = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, "FirstServlet.war", file);
            PutObjectResult res = service.s3().putObject(object);
            System.out.println(res.getClass());

            CreateApplicationVersionRequest versionRequest = new CreateApplicationVersionRequest();
            versionRequest.setVersionLabel("First Servlet");
            versionRequest.setApplicationName("SampleApplication");
            S3Location s3 = new S3Location(bucket, "FirstServlet.war");
            versionRequest.setSourceBundle(s3);
            CreateApplicationVersionResult resu = service.beansTalk().createApplicationVersion(versionRequest);
            System.out.println(resu);

            UpdateEnvironmentRequest updateRequest = new UpdateEnvironmentRequest();
            updateRequest.setEnvironmentId("xxx");
            updateRequest.setVersionLabel("First Servlet");
            UpdateEnvironmentResult result = service.beansTalk().updateEnvironment(updateRequest);
            System.out.println(result)
```